# Installing Perl Modules on Android OS

Tags: android, perl, cpan, sl4a

Are there an options to install Perl modules like LWP on Android (on SL4A environment ).  Also, are there prepackaged Perl modules that can be installed on Android, and is there an option to see which modules are installed using the Android Debug Bridge.

Comment: If there is a native Perl installation, then you should be able to install modules via `cpan` on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

No. No. Perl can surely be asked to provide this, but you can start by looking under

```
$ ls /data/data/com.googlecode.perlforandroid/files/perl/5.10.0/
```

SL4A's perl actually comes with CPAN.pm - but not all of its dependencies, as you'll see with the errors you get with

```
$ perl -MCPAN -eshell
```

I used CPAN.pm on a Sharp Zaurus, running OpenBSD, and I used a CPAN.pm-less hack to install modules off of CPAN so that the process would be easier on my 64MB of RAM.  My Galaxy Tab has slightly better hardware.  But at present, nobody's done the work to make (unrooted) Android a comfortable home for Perl -- and as Perl is poorly-suited to Android app development, that may remain the case for a while.

EDIT: Well, try these:

1. [App::FatPacker](http://search.cpan.org/~dgl/App-FatPacker-0.009006/lib/App/FatPacker.pm)
2. [App::cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/lib/App/cpanminus.pm)

Answer (score 4):

Only "Pure Perl" modules that aren't coded in C (aka., "XS" modules) can be added to SL4A's version of Perl. You can view what modules are included in that simply by downloading the [Perl zip installed by SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/downloads/detail?name=perl_r9.zip&can=2&q=).

In SL4A's current version (Perl 5.10), modules are fairly limited due to the incomplete compile process used. A new version of the [Perl for Android Interpreter](http://code.google.com/p/perl-android-apk/) should be available here soon, which will have more of the standard Perl Core modules, along with a description of how to compile more from CPAN.